# PHP - Pass mysql @variable in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following SQL that I'd like to run on MySQL DB via PHP.

**ERROR**

```
syntax error  check the
 manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@rn := if(@prevDate=eve_date
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT eve_date, 
       cust_name, 
       item_id, 
       Sum(item_bundle_size) sumsize 
FROM   (SELECT eve_date, 
               cust_name, 
               item_id, 
               item_bundle_size, 
               @rn := IF(@prevdate = eve_date, IF (@previtem = item_id, @rn, 
                      IF (@previtem := item_id, @rn + 1 
                      , @rn + 
                      1)), 
                      IF 
                             (@prevdate := eve_date, 
                      IF (@previtem := item_id, 1, 1), 1 
                      ) 
                      ) rn 
        FROM   cust_sales_hist 
               CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, 
                                  @prevdate := NULL, 
                                  @previtem := NULL) t 
        WHERE  cust_name = 'Cust1' 
               AND eve_date BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-08-05' 
        ORDER  BY eve_date, 
                  item_bundle_size DESC) t 
WHERE  rn <= 4 
GROUP  BY eve_date, 
          cust_name, 
          item_id 
ORDER  BY eve_date, 
          cust_name, 
          sumsize DESC
```

I looked up SO for examples that advised about splitting the query into several parts. However, in my case, it looks like I gotta run this as one due to the requirement of the output. The SQL fiddle for this query is here in case needed - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a5d08/5

I'd truly appreciate any help to get me moving here please.

Comment: So, where's your php code?

Comment: Oh sorry. Didn't realize I hadn't put that in. Will update the question in a few mins.

Comment: @u_mulder - Actually, putting the code in here is hard coz,  I use a class to manage the database things. I have over a 100 queries that I've already got working with the exiting system. So, the SQL execution system. I go through the stages of SQL prepare, SQL execute &  SQL fetch result. The problem in the current scenario is just the `@` symbol. If you could guide me on is there a way to escape it, it'd be awesome please. I've also tried `\@`  hoping it works (no real logic. Just trying a few things), but it doesn't obviously.

Comment: rather then writing a complex query in you php script ,i would recommend you to create a stored procedure in MySQL and call it simply in you application.

Comment: Your query looks OK to me. Make sure you have the `,` after `item_bundle_size` in the actual code.

Comment: Hello Barmar - Thank you. The SQL runs fine when run from command line. It's the PHP part that is turning out to be  pain. That is , running the SQL through PHP

Comment: Since the query runs in sqlfiddle, there's no syntax error in it. And there's nothing in there that PHP would treat specially.

Comment: Thanks Aman. That's a good idea. I'll have a think. For now I'd love to know how to get around the `@` variable.

Comment: @variable should work fine from PHP, it's not treated any differently from any other character. You must have mistyped something when you copied the query into the PHP script.

Comment: Hmm.. That's strange.. i'll reinspect my work, keeping fingers crossed to spot a typo I've made

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: It end up being a carriage return character that was breaking the query into 2 parts. Even though I had enclosed the whole query in double quotes, something was going wrong. Following Barmar's advice, I paid special attention to special characters & it works!! Thank you heaps & tons Barmer. Can't thank you enough. Please do post it in the answer section. I'll accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Barmer above, the code had a special character that not visible strangely that was splitting the query into 2 parts & hence the problem. Worked around this. Thanks to Barmer